Kindle does not display font-style properly, and all other epub readers does
Kindle does not display font-style properly, and all other epub readers does.
I did choose standard font:
.new-font{
       font-family: Courier,sans-serif;
     }

and used it normally:
<p class="new-font">And here shall be font courier but it's not in Kindle</p>

But font is not displayed on Kindle. Other epub readers like Calibre works fine...
It does on PC and Android. I have latest versions. On PC I have version 2.4.0 70904.

I found reason. In some other xhtml file in that ebook I specified
<style>
 body {
  font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
 }
</style>

and it took priority over all. It is not according to CSS standard as more specific class name shall take priority over general style (especially when defined in other xhtml file)
So it seems Kindle at least for windows and android doesn't display good priority for CSS styling (and maybe other attributes too). Here is example where this issue is seen:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops">
<head>
<style>
 body {
  font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
 }
 .new-font{
   font-family: Courier,sans-serif;
 }
</style>
  <title>simple font</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Font bug demonstration - Herer is font arial correctly</p>
  <p class="new-font">And here shall be font courier but it's not in Kindle</p>
</body>
</html>

So fix would be never use css attributes on body but maybe have some inner div...
